# How to grab pixels of a rectangle

Tags: java, image, pixel

How to grab pixels of a rectangle and how to get color of grabbed pixels in Java...

Comment: it will be closed in 10 minutes.

Comment: rumana, you will have to edit your question to be more specific. Are you talking about images?

Comment: you should try to provide some more context and what code you have written/tried so far in order to allow people to really understand your problem and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you want to grab pixels of a rectangle in an existing [Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)), have a look at the [PixelGrabber](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html) class. The example in the Javadocs shows how to get the color of each grabbed pixel.